# Cutting a texture from a sprite sheet with pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, graphics, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to get smaller textures from a sprite sheet using pointer arithmetic, but the results are not quite the same as I expect to see.

Basically, I am using this function to do such a thing:

```
internal void
GetShiftedTexture(texture_t* Texture, v2 Shift, v2 NewDim)
{
    u32 ShiftX = Shift.x;
    u32 ShiftY = Shift.y;

    Texture->Width  = NewDim.x;
    Texture->Height = NewDim.y;

    u32 Pitch = Texture->Width * sizeof(u32);
    Texture->Memory = (u32*)((u8*)Texture->Memory + ShiftX * sizeof(u32) + ShiftY * Pitch);
}
```

Could It be that I am just using wrong arithmetics there? Thanks

Comment: I guess the sprite sheet stores the sprites in a rectangular grid? The memory for each sprite in the sprite sheet will not be contiguous. Each row of the sprite sheet will be a certain number of bytes wide, say **RowPitch** bytes. Then the second row of an individual sprite will start **RowPitch** bytes after the start of the first row of the sprite. The `texture_t` needs to store that information and take it into account when reading the rows of data for a sprite out of the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

1. **What is the topology of your Texture Atlas?**

   do you have sample input/output?  Do you have more images in row or in column or in both? Only 1 image per row and no x resolution change allow you to just update pointer instead of memory copy.
2. **Also you change `Texture->Memory` that looks like a huge memory leak to me**

   You know if you cut the textures like this you lost your original pointer and memory manager will get nasty trying to release it later ... So you should allocate new chunk of memory, copy and then release the old one, or remember original pointer and releasing only that once needed.
3. **you changed `Texture->Width` prior to computing pitch that is a mistake**

   So you should swap the order of lines to remedy (moving the pitch line before the width change).
4. **you never check new resolution and shift**

   they might cross out of bounds of your texture ...